# MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0X with JDBC can't find MySQL Client (CMake)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm trying to add MySQL Connector/C++ (8.0.29) to my project. I'm doing this from sources as submodule

```
add_subdirectory(other/mysql)
```

Also I will use legacy JDBC API, so I changed default state of config option in `other/mysql/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_config_option(WITH_JDBC BOOL DEFAULT ON
 "Whether to build a variant of connector library which implements legacy JDBC API"
)
```

But when I'm trying to configure project it says

```
Legacy library soversion: 9
Looking for MySQL Client library:
CMake Error at other/mysql/jdbc/cmake/DepFindMySQL.cmake:135 (message):
  Could not find MySQL headers at:

  Point at MySQL client library location using WITH_MYSQL or
  MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR, MYSQL_LIB_DIR settings.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  other/mysql/jdbc/cmake/DepFindMySQL.cmake:615 (main)
  other/mysql/cdk/cmake/dependency.cmake:45 (include)
  other/mysql/jdbc/CMakeLists.txt:147 (find_dependency)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have mysql-client(5.7.38-1ubuntu18.04) package installed and I'm not sure what to do

Comment: For **build** something which uses a library you need a **dev** package: [libmysqlclient-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/bionic/libmysqlclient-dev).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh yeah, i had newer version of this package, installing 5.7 one helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing package [libmysqlclient-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/bionic/libmysqlclient-dev) same version as [mysql-client](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/bionic/mysql-client) helped

Answer (score 0):

> *Also I will use legacy JDBC API, so I changed default state of config option in other/mysql/CMakeLists.txt*

You could add `set(WITH_JDBC ON)` in your root CMakeLists.txt or give as a cmake command option `-DWITH_JDBC=ON` instead of changing original library.